# Is it possible to catch an asynchronous script before it is run?

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous

So I found this script which allows you to edit a web page before it is loaded, or at least that is the impression that I get from it. My question is, if I wanted to remove an asynchronous script and this was the first thing run on the web page will it take care of this?

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest,
    content,
    doc,
    scripts;

xhr.open( "GET", document.URL, false );
xhr.send(null);
content = xhr.responseText;

doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument(""+(document.title || ""));

doc.open();
doc.write(content);
doc.close();


scripts = doc.getElementsByTagName("script");
//Modify scripts as you please
[].forEach.call( scripts, function( script ) {
    script.removeAttribute("src");
    script.innerHTML = 'alert("hello world");';
});

//Doing this will activate all the modified scripts and the "old page" will be gone as the document is replaced
document.replaceChild( document.importNode(doc.documentElement, true), document.documentElement);
```

i.e. if the script above was in a file called `prerun.js` or just in `<script>` tags at the top of the page, and I had a script (unsure as to whether it is actually an async or sync script) called `thescript.js` and I wanted to get rid of `thescript.js` before it is loaded/run

this is what my `<head>` tag will look like :

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="prerun.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="thescript.js"></script>
</head>
```

If it does not get rid of the script before it is loaded/run what would be the required way to do so?

Comment: If you are able to modify the page that loads `thescript.js`, why not just remove the loading/invocation of it?

Comment: @PatrickQ so thats what I do with `script.removeAttribute("src")` but I am not sure whether or not it actually gets rid of the script before it is run.

Comment: @Adjit "async" controls when the script is *run* (or rather it allows it to be deferred), but not when the script is queued to be fetched/run. That is, I would not make any assumptions counter to this *once the HTML is parsed* (i.e. the element is added to the DOM) - once that happens, there is no reliable way to "stop execution" or "do something first". And the [relevant] HTML *must* be parsed prior to being able to access the relevant DOM elements.

Comment: What I'm saying is that if you are able to manually edit the source (which you seem to be able to do, since you are adding `<script type="text/javascript" src="prerun.js"></script>`), why not just manually remove the line `<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="thescript.js"></script>`?

Comment: @PatrickQ assuming you cannot remove it.

Comment: @user2864740 so basically what you are saying is, this script is going to run one way or the other?